# Use helper methods within a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I defined a helper `abc()` in `annotations_helper.rb`. What do I have to do such that I can use this method in `annotations_controller.rb`?

Answer (score 1):

In general helpers are supposed to be "view helpers" and not called from controllers.

You probably want to put something like that in application_controller.rb

Answer (score 1):

This is usually not a good practice to use a helper in your controllers. You should try to move the logic inside a model or if the logic is too generic, you should move that to `lib/some_lib.rb` and `include` that in your model to use.

However check out this [blog post](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/1799) if you really want to do this. Don't forget to read the comments.